# Problem in translating from MIPS to C

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

I was trying to solve this homework assignment but was unable to come up with a solution. Below is the problem,

> Translate the following MIPS code into a high-level language program.
>   Assume that $t0, $t1, and $t2 contain base addresses of arrays A, B
>   and C respectively.

```
add $t4, $zero, $zero
Loop:
add $t5, $t4, $t1
lw $t6, 0($t5)
add $t5, $t4, $t2
lw $t7, 0($t5)
add $t6, $t6, $t7
add $t5, $t4, $t0
sw $t6, 0($t5)
addi $t4, $t4, 4
slti $t5, $t4, 256
bne $t5, $zero, Loop
```

> ```
> Also find the decimal value in the offset field of bne
> ```
>
> instruction.

Here is what I have tried, but I yet don't find the position of `256`.

```
int *temp4 = 0;
while(1)
{
    *int temp5 = temp4 +B[0];
    a:
        *int temp6 = temp5;
        temp5 = C[0] + temp4;
        *temp7 = temp5;
        temp6 = temp6 + temp7;
        temp5 = temp4 + A[0];
        temp6 = temp5;
        temp4 += 4;
        if(temp5 < temp4)
            goto __;
        if(temp5 != 0)
            goto a;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are overthinking things.

What that code does is something like this

```
for (int i =0 ; i< 64; i++){

   A[i] = B[i] + C[i];

}
```

Not going to explain why, since this <strike>looks a lot like</strike> is homework.

> Here is what I have tried, but I yet don't find the position of 256.

You are mixing things up. See that `i` at the end of `slti` ? That means that it uses an inmediate operand, in this case `256`. So what the `slti $t5, $t4, 256` instruction is doing, is setting a `1` in register `$t5` if the contents of `$t4` are lower than 256. Otherwise, `$t5` gets a `0`.

Consequently, the loop will take 256/4 iterations, since the `bne` will fallthrough (i.e not jump) only when the contents of `$t4` are greater than `256`.

Comment: In the statement,add $t5, $t4, $t1, t1 is not initialized to a value. Can you please elaborate what would it hold?

Comment: `$t1` contains the base address of array B. Its an assumption.
In mips, as simple as `la $t1,arrayB`